# Which carnivores can be in the same enclosure?

Tags: jurassic-world-evolution

For example: Dilophosaurus and I believe it was Velociraptor can be put together.

However a Ceratosaurus and a Deinonychus can not.

Comment: While i can't give you a list (and this is the reason for a comment not an answer) you can do the same as in my answer for your other question and simply try it out on the sandbox island